# Spring cloud stream kafka and Feign client result in consume message repeat

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-feign

In my project, I use spring-cloud-stream-kafka, and `@StreamListener` received Message, When  processing this message I used `FeignClient` to call another service.

but I didn't call that service without exception, and I received the same message again.

Comment: You need to provide much more information, debug logs etc.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're describing a situation where you have code receiving a streams message and an exception takes place in that code (specifically in the feign-based call to another service but it doesn't really matter where the error happens). You seem surprised that the same code then executes again. This is expected as retry is part of the default error handling behaviour for spring cloud streams. By default 3 attempts (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling).